# Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE JpaVendorAdapter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was using version **1.5.4.RELEASE** of Spring Boot and the application compiles normally, but when I upgrade to version **1.5.6.RELEASE** the application does not compile anymore, I looked for the reference of the classes and interfaces, but I did not find anything about it in this version, can anyone help me?

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**PersistenceJPAConfig.java:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.demo" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/mywebapp.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false) })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Value("${driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${userDataBase}")
    private String userDataBase;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernatedialect;
    @Value("${show_sql:false}")
    private String show_sql;
    @Value("${validationQuery:select 1 from dual}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Autowired
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Bean()
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("MyWebApp");
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.demo" });
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.afterPropertiesSet();
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(userDataBase);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(2);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(15);
        dataSource.setMinIdle(2);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60 * 60);
        dataSource.setLogAbandoned(true);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        dataSource.setTestOnReturn(true);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernatedialect);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", show_sql);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

the error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Try purging local maven repo then updating. `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` or just navigatingt to your `.m2` directory and wiping out the repository.

Comment: This worked perfectly, put as an answer for me to approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason this happen when updating Spring Boot Parent versions it updates a lot of transitive dependencies it uses. These can fail to download correctly and manifest with import errors.

You can clear the repository either with,

`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` or just navigating to your .m2 directory and wiping out the repository

Using the maven plugin has some advantages like being able to pass arguments, or ignore transitive dependencies etc.

You can also see if a jar failed to download correctly in some cases if you open the maven console in Eclipse, or just run `mvn install` from the CLI. It will normally `warn` that a jar has a bad header or it could not be read.